# Microsoft Graph API report is empty

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to get Outlook reports using Microsoft Graph API. I am getting the reports for two tenants, let's say Tenant A and Tenant B.

For some of the API, I am getting empty reports (i.e. I am getting just the header).

For example, when I query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period='D7')
```

I get:

```
Report Refresh Date,Send,Receive,Read,Report Date,Report Period
```

Some of the API calls work only for tenant A and some work only for Tenant B.

Can anybody tell me why it works like this?

Answer (score 1):

I got a response from the Microsoft support team that if you do not use the service, there will be no reports to show. Once you begin using the service, it will reflect that. It can take 24-72 hours for reports to be generated.

And the following two links gives us more information on the topic

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-analytics-and-reports/teams-reporting-reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide